# React Native - MaterialCommunityIcons typescript definition for icon name

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-vector-icons

I'm trying to find out the type definitions for the icon name of MaterialCommunityIcons, since i am intending to use it for props.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```js
React.ComponentProps<typeof MaterialCommunityIcons>['name']
```

Comment: Another solution is: `let iconName: keyof typeof MaterialCommunityIcons.glyphMap;`

Comment: The accepted answer doesn't work for me. When I try to use a prop with that type as the `name` prop for a `MaterialCommunityIcons` element it gives a typescript error. Using the suggestion from @Ying works perfectly. I'll suggest an edit with that change.

Answer (score -2):

Check out this site.
provides icon name and preview.

https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/

Comment: Be more descriptive about your answer,

Comment: @SenseKim I am trying to find the Type definition, not the actual icon names, because I am using `icon name` as props

Comment: @PaoloVincent What is the type you are talking about, for example? like 'Ionicons', 'MaterialCommunityIcons'? You can check and use it on that site. Another way is to find out what kind of icon is provided when [link](https://icons.expo.fyi/) clicks 'Filters' here.

Comment: @SenseKim, Typescript. i want to get the type of the name prop of MaterialCommunityIcon, I want to specify the type instead of just 'string'

Comment: @SenseKim, ```React.ComponentProps<typeof MaterialCommunityIcons>['name']``` this is what i was looking for